# Ajax post only triggers once

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

Hello all I am having issues with an ajax function. I am trying to post to a database that I have and then refresh a table that displays the database info. The process works once, it posts to the database and then refreshes, however, after that it no longer posts but continues to refresh the table.

here is the code:

```
<button id="refresh-btn" type="button">Add New</button>
                
<script>
 $("#refresh-btn").on('click', function(){
                             
    var f = $('#form1');
                            
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data: f.serialize()
    });
                                
    $( "#mytable" ).load( "contacttest.php #mytable" );
                           
});
</script>
```

After checking my developer console it seems the issue is that I get undefined array key issues due to the form being refreshed. I am assuming it is not being reposted but what would be the best/correct way of implementing this?

Comment: `I am trying to post to a database that I have and then refresh a table`...in the code you've shown, these processes will happen simultaneously, not sequentially (because AJAX calls are asynchronous). Is that the intention? Is it maybe even part of the issue? I don't see how it could refresh the table without posting the form though...if it reaches the `.load()` command, it _must_ have also executed the `$.ajax` command above it. Maybe that post request is failing sometimes? You said there are no JS console errors, but what about PHP errors?

Comment: That was my thought and why this has been such an issue for me. In my console no errors are thrown. Unless there is a separate spot where php errors would show. I am slightly new to ajax.

Comment: The console only shows JavaScript errors. PHP errors would show in the PHP error log, if error logging is configured, or in the output from the PHP (which for an AJAX request, you could see in the Response tab of the AJAX request, if you click on it from the browser's Network tool). Or it might not be an error as such, but could be a bug. But also you can use the Network tool as well to check the AJAX requests and see what is being sent and received from the server in each case, and ensure it all contains what you expect (or not!)

Comment: Thank you for that I took a look at the preview for the php script and it throws a bunch of array key issues when trying to post a second time.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles on this and still needs help I answered my own question. The issue is that when refreshing the table since the button is outside of it the form doesn't get reposted so the php script is unable to locate the variables. In order to fix this issue simply change the button from `<button id="refresh-btn" type="button">Add New</button>` to `<button id="refresh-btn" type="submit" form="form1">Add New</button>` This causes the button to repost the form after the refresh.

Comment: Ah so you mean this refresh is done by a different button than the initial posting of the form? Yes that would explain it. I don't think the question contained a [mre] for anyone to spot that from here. Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Although...since you're using JS to submit the form via $.ajax, and locating the form via its ID in JS, and serializing that, it really shouldn't matter. Unless the JS is not in fact doing anything, and the button/form is just posting normally? My initial reaction to your answer was "great", but now I'm thinking "WTF", I can't see how it makes sense. But then again we can only see a fraction of your code, so I'm mostly speculating.

Comment: Ya sorry I posted the code I thought was necessary and the issue. After your helpful tip about checking network, it made me realize the issue was slightly different than the original. I do agree though it should still be working because it grabs the info from the form via the serialize. It is a weird interaction that should be working but isn't. I have it fixed and hopefully will not have any errors with it in the future.

Comment: Have you used the JS debugger to check that the `$("#refresh-btn").on('click', function(){` function is even firing, and that the page isn't just posting back when the button is clicked?